# How to enable button when checbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jscript

I have codes like this

```
<div class="checkbox">

            <input type="checkbox" id="checkme" value ="accept"/>
                        <label>I have read and agree to the terms and conditions</label>
                                    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>
```

I was trying to put this Jscript below of codes:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var the_terms = $("#checkme");

    the_terms.click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#sub1").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#sub1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
}); 
                        </script>
```

However it does not work at all. I already follow all guides on internet. Anyone can help what part i did wrong? Is there any additional codes beside these?'

Oh and this on php format

EDIT:
Done this too

```
                                                    <script>
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sub1');
checker.onchange = function() {
  sendbtn.disabled = !!this.checked;
};
                        </script>
```

But how do i change to disable when unchecked?

Comment: can you check your console if there is any error

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnd1y3za/1/ did you include the jquery library?

Comment: Jquery library? sorry im just started programming so i have no idea

Comment: if your going to use jquery, you have to include the jquery library, you need to start with some basics: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
paste this code over your script tag.

Comment: Works fine now. Thanks shubham :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jquery change event like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#checkme').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#sub1").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#sub1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
  $('#id_of_your_checkbox').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#id_of_your_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
          $('#id_of_your_button').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149917/disable-or-enable-submit-button-on-checkbox-checked-event

Comment: If you think another answer in its entirety covers this issue, you could have  flagged it as a duplicate, instead of replicating the answer. Unless your answer is a modified version of the linked one, but that doesn't seem to be the case.